# Will it be possible to find which service is interacting with UI?

Tags: c++, windows, service, ipc

We have MFC application which has several UIs and different services are interacting with UI. Will it be possible to guess (I am saying guess because there can be more than one service is used by UI or vice versa.) which service is actually interacting with my UI?

I tried to use Process Explorer and Spy++ but no luck so far.

Some services are .Net services others are native Windows services.

Comment: I always thought it was the other way around, that some user interface was interacting with some services?

Comment: What do you mean by "interacting"?  By "service" do you mean a system service application, i.e., something you can see in the "Services" administrative tool?  Note that system services applications and ordinary interactive applications can't communicate via window messages, so they can't be "interacting" in that sense.

Comment: Yes I am talking about ("services.msc") Windows services. May not be Windows Messages, but they must be interacting using some IPC.

Comment: There are a lot of different types of IPC.  You could try using `handle.exe` (available from the MS web site) and check for any objects that both the application and a service have open.  Also `netstat -a -n -b` to see if they are communicating via TCP/IP.  Failing that, trial and error: if the UI behaves differently when a particular service is stopped, or if using the UI makes the service start up again, they are probably interacting.